# Angular image getting by http

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm need get image by httpclient in new angular but i dont how do it.

```
  private imageLoad(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
    .map(e => this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(URL.createObjectURL(e)));
  }
```

It throws error like that

> Invalid response. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

how to fix that?

Comment: will you be able to create a stackblitz for your question? Anyway way use HttpClientModule.

Comment: you are downloading image right ?

Comment: yes, i'm downloading image to insert it into html.

Comment: i think it's a CORS  problem, your base url is not allowed on the server

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are download image file , to download file do like this

```
 imageUrl: any;
 DownloadFile():void
  {
    this.getFile("http://localhost:1800/api/demo/GetTestFile")
    .subscribe(fileData => 
      {
        let b:any = new Blob([fileData], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
        this.imageUrl= window.URL.createObjectURL(b);
      }
    );
  }

  public getFile(path: string):Observable<any>{
    let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob});
    return this.http.get(path, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <Blob>response.blob())  ;
  }
```

---

html

```
<img [src]="imageUrl" />
```